# Fastlane retrieve provisioning profile path from identifier

Tags: xcode, code-signing, provisioning-profile, fastlane

**Is there any fastlane/CLI tool that you can find the path and name of a provisioning profile, based on the UDID?**

---

I am trying to set up fastlane to do the code signing. I am using `match`, but it's not working for my use case, because the provisioning profile needs to be changed.

I have 2 lanes, both using **RELEASE** configuration:

- `submit_app_store`, with `match App Store` profile, to upload a Release build to Test Flight
- `deploy_qa_prod`, with `match AdHoc` profile, to upload a Release build to our QA platform

I am trying to call `update_project_provisioning`, but I need to give it a path to the profile and I only have the specifier of the provisioning profiles, like `match AdHoc APP_ID`.

I would like a command that transforms this specifier into a path.

---

Fastlane code:

```
lane :deploy_qa_prod do
  configuration = "Release"
  app_identifier = ...
  provisioning_profile = "match AdHoc #{app_identifier}"
  # In the other lane: provisioning_profile = "match AppStore #{app_identifier}"

  sync_code_signing(
    type: "adhoc",
    app_identifier: app_identifier,
    readonly: true
  )

  update_project_provisioning(
     xcodeproj: ...,
     target_filter: ...,
     # profile: provisioning_profile, <--- This is the problematic line
     build_configuration: configuration
  )

  build_app(
     scheme: ...,
     workspace: ...,
     configuration: configuration
     export_options: {
       method: "ad-hoc",
       provisioningProfiles: {
         app_identifier => provisioning_profile
       }
     }
   )

   pilot(......)
   # In the other lane: upload_to_qa(......)
```

Comment: Did you figure this out @Lord Zsolt? I've got the same need.

Comment: Is there are any update about this issue?

Comment: @Lucky_girl Yeah, added my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Recommended solution:

I moved away from using only `DEBUG` and `RELEASE` configurations.

Instead, I defined 5 different configurations:

- Develop (Beta)
- Develop (Prod)
- AdHoc (Beta)
- AdHoc (Prod) *
- AppStore (Prod) *

* My original `RELEASE` configurations, when posting this question.

This way, I can have separate certificate and provisioning profiles defined for each configuration, and I no longer need to change them from fastlane.

If you defined some User-Defined properties in `Build Settings`, avoid duplicating them 5 times by using `.xcconfig` files. You can read more about them [here for example](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/let-s-setup-your-ios-environments).

---

### Hacky solution, directly answering my question

I do not recommend doing this, and instead go with separate configurations. But if you need a temporary quick fix, then:

Unfortunately (or fortunately), there's no non-hacky way of doing this.

What I noticed is that the `sync_code_signing` (aka `match`) calls `sigh` under the hood, which will create environmental variables for the downloaded provisioning profiles.

The name of these variables follows the following format: `sigh_#{app_identifier}_#{match_type}_profile-path` (Ex: `sigh_com.yourDomain.yourAppName_adhoc_profile-path`)

You can then use this variable when you call `update_project_provisioning`:

```
    app_identifier = ...
    match_type = "adhoc"
    configuration = "Release"

    sync_code_signing(
        type: match_type,
        app_identifier: app_identifier,
        readonly: true
    )

    profile_path = ENV["sigh_#{app_identifier}_#{match_type}_profile-path"]
 
    update_project_provisioning(
      xcodeproj: ...,
      target_filter: ...,
      profile: profile_path,
      build_configuration: configuration
    )
    
    ...
```